# picking up correct patient type using case expression

Tags: sql, oracle, case

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlNot.png)the following code picks up patient bathing.  there is a case expression at the end called PATIENT_TYPE.

A patient can be defined as type by 1 of 3 things. If they are in ICU they are CHG.  If they have a specific type of central line they are CHG or STANDARD.

If they are not in icu and do not have a central line they are defined as STANDARD.

A patient can have 2 different central lines at the same time. 1 line can be standard, 1 line can be chg.  A patient can be bathed multiple times during a day.  A patient may show multiple lines of data, due to the number of times they were bathed on that day.

The patient type needs to be consistent during the patients stay so they get the correct bathing.

Patient a will display 2 patient types if the lines are 2 different lines.  So on 3/1 joe had a cl so dispklay the cl with patient type chg.  3/2 joe had the cl removed, but it was there part of the day so still display patient type chg.  on 3/3 joe is still in unit but no central line. His room type is standard, so his patient type is now standard because he is not in icu or has a central line.

I need to be able to display the correct patient type. the lines need to display during the time in a specific unit.

```
CL-- PULL ALL CL PATIENTS IN TIME FRAME OF REPORT
AS
(
select DISTINCT
to_char(a.effective_time,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFFECT_DATE,
a.effective_time,
L.PAT_ID,
l.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN 'CL' 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN 'CL' END AS CL,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN  1
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN  1
ELSE NULL END AS CL_FLAG,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN  L.FLO_MEAS_ID 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN  L.FLO_MEAS_ID 
ELSE NULL END AS FLO_MEAS_ID,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN L.DESCRIPTION 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN L.DESCRIPTION 
ELSE NULL END AS DISP_NAME,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN L.IP_LDA_ID 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN L.IP_LDA_ID 
ELSE NULL END AS IP_LDA_ID,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT 
ELSE NULL END AS PLACEMENT_INSTANT,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN L.REMOVAL_INSTANT
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN L.REMOVAL_INSTANT 
ELSE NULL END AS REMOVAL_INSTANT,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN TO_CHAR(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN TO_CHAR(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT,'MM/DD/YYYY') 
ELSE NULL END AS PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)THEN TO_CHAR(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT,'MM/DD/YYYY')
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time) THEN TO_CHAR(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT,'MM/DD/YYYY')
ELSE NULL END AS REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE,
CASE 
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120   AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120   
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =888300450    AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arterial Line%'    THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =888300450    
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arterial Line%'    THEN 'STANDARD'

WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'STANDARD'

WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'STANDARD'

WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'STANDARD'

WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'STANDARD'

WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID IN (26739,26747,26751,26751,26751,26755,26768,8882819,8882826,888304620,888304630,888304640,888304650,888304660,888304670,
3042000201, 3042000202, 3042673901, 8887095100,8887095120,8887095120,8887095120,8883040100580,8883040100583,8883040100584)  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID IN (26739,26747,26751,26751,26751,26755,26768,8882819,8882826,888304620,888304630,888304640,888304650,888304660,888304670,
3042000201, 3042000202, 3042673901, 8887095100,8887095120,8887095120,8887095120,8883040100580,8883040100583,8883040100584)THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120   AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120   
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'STANDARD'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arteriovenous Graft%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arteriovenous  Graft%'    THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Hero Graft%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095120  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =888300450    AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arterial Line%'   THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND L.FLO_MEAS_ID =888300450    
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arterial Line%'    THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Tenckhoff Catheter%'   THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Hero Graft%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Hero Graft%'   THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous Fistula%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arteriovenous Graft%' THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous Graft%'  THEN 'CHG'
WHEN TRUNC(L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(a.effective_time) AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)
AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE  '%Arteriovenous  Graft%'    THEN 'CHG'
WHEN L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(L.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(a.effective_time)AND  L.FLO_MEAS_ID =8887095100  
AND L.DESCRIPTION NOT LIKE '%Arteriovenous  Graft%' THEN 'CHG'
ELSE NULL END AS CL_PATIENT_TYPE-- PICKING PATIENT TYPE DEFINED BY LINE TYPES
From IP_LDA_NOADDSINGLE L
JOIN CLARITY_ADT A
ON L.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = A.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
where L.FLO_MEAS_ID IN (
26739,  --  Temporary Central Line
26747,  --  Permanent (tunneled) Catheter
)AND
(a.effective_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1)
)
,
CL2
AS
(
select DISTINCT
L.EFFECT_DATE,
L.effective_time,
L.PAT_ID,
L.IP_LDA_ID,
l.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
L.CL_FLAG,
L.FLO_MEAS_ID,
L.DISP_NAME,
L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT,
L.REMOVAL_INSTANT,
L.PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE,
L.REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE,
L.CL_PATIENT_TYPE,-- PICKING PATIENT TYPE DEFINED BY LINE TYPES FROM CL L
MIN(L.CL_PATIENT_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY L.PAT_ID,L.EFFECT_DATE)  AS MIN_CLPAT,
MAX(L.CL_PATIENT_TYPE) OVER (PARTITION BY L.PAT_ID,L.EFFECT_DATE)  AS MAX_CLPAT,
L.CL
FROM CL L
WHERE L.CL_FLAG=1 
)
,
PTS -- PATIENTS
AS
(select distinct
DEP.REV_LOC_ID AS HOSPITAL,
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID,
dep.department_name,
to_char(adt.effective_time,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFFECT_DATE,
ADT.EFFECTIVE_TIME,
ADT.PAT_ID,
PEH.Y_MRN,
PEH.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
peh.inpatient_data_id,
peh.hosp_admsn_time,
CASE WHEN ADT.DEPARTMENT_ID NOT IN 
(2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235 ) THEN 'STANDARD'WHEN ADT.DEPARTMENT_ID IN (2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235 )  THEN 'CHG'END AS RM_PATIENT_TYPE--PICKING UP PATIENT TYPE DEFINED BY ROOM 
from
clarity_adt adt
left outer join
pat_enc_hsp peh on
adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = peh.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
LEFT OUTER join
clarity_dep dep
on adt.DEPARTMENT_ID = dep.DEPARTMENT_ID
where
((adt.effective_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1)
and trunc (adt.effective_time) <> trunc (peh.hosp_admsn_time)
) and adt.event_type_c in (6)
and PEH.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = '1' 
AND adt.event_subtype_c <> 2
)
,
FMEAS -- BATHING FLOW MEASURE
AS
(
select distinct
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID,
dep.department_name,
ADT.PAT_ID,
PEH.Y_MRN,
PEH.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID AS FMEAS_PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
NULL AS y_inpatient_dat,
to_char(ADT.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFFECT_DATE,
NULL AS RECORDED_TIME,
TO_CHAR(ADT.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS RECORDED_DATE,
NULL AS meas_value,
NULL AS Standard_Bath,
NULL AS CHG
from
clarity_adt adt
LEFT OUTER join
pat_enc_hsp peh
on
adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = peh.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN
clarity_dep dep
on 
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID = dep.DEPARTMENT_ID
where
DEP.REV_LOC_ID IN (2133)--, 4313,4314,5133)
AND
 (adt.effective_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1) and adt.event_type_c in (6)
and PEH.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = '1' 
AND adt.event_subtype_c <> 2

UNION

select distinct
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID,
dep.department_name,
ADT.PAT_ID,
PEH.Y_MRN,
PEH.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID AS FMEAS_PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
fmeas.y_inpatient_dat,
to_char(ADT.EFFECTIVE_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS EFFECT_DATE,
Fmeas.Recorded_Time AS RECORDED_TIME,
TO_CHAR(fMEAS.RECORDED_TIME,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS RECORDED_DATE,
fmeas.meas_value,
CASE WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE 'Standard%' THEN 'Standard bathing wipes' 
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Standard bathing wipes%' THEN 'Standard bathing wipes' 
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Indep%' THEN 'Independent Shower' END AS Standard_Bath,
CASE WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%CHG (Chlorhexidine) bathing wipes%' THEN 'CHG (Chlorhexidine) bathing wipes'
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Independent Shower%' THEN 'Independent Shower'
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Incontience Care%'then 'Incontience Care'
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Bath not given - Patient refused CHG  %'then 'Bath not given - Patient refused CHG'
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Bath not given - CHG contraindicated%'then 'Bath not given - CHG contraindicated' 
WHEN Fmeas.MEAS_VALUE LIKE 'Bath not given - Other Comment%'then 'Bath not given - Other Comment' END AS CHG
from
clarity_adt adt
LEFT OUTER join
pat_enc_hsp peh
on
adt.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = peh.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
LEFT OUTER join
Ip_Flwsht_Meas fmeas 
on 
fmeas.y_inpatient_dat=peh.inpatient_data_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN
clarity_dep dep
on 
adt.DEPARTMENT_ID = dep.DEPARTMENT_ID
where
(fmeas.RECORDED_TIME between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1)
and
 (adt.effective_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1)
and
fmeas.flo_meas_id='888305660' 
and adt.event_type_c in (6)
and 
PEH.ADT_PAT_CLASS_C = '1' 
AND 
adt.event_subtype_c <> 2
)
,
PT2-- JOIN FLOWMEAS TO PATS
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
P.HOSPITAL,
P.DEPARTMENT_ID,
P.department_name,
P.EFFECT_DATE,
P.effective_time,
P.PAT_ID,
P.Y_MRN,
P.hosp_admsn_time,
P.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
P.RM_PATIENT_TYPE,
F.RECORDED_TIME,
F.RECORDED_DATE,
F.meas_value,
F.Standard_Bath,
F.CHG,
CASE 
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE IS NULL THEN 'NOT DOCUMENTED' 
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE ='Standard bathing wipes' THEN 'WASHED / GIVEN' 
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Indep%' THEN 'WASHED / GIVEN'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE 'Indep%' THEN 'WASHED / GIVEN'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%CHG (Chlorhexidine) bathing wipes%' THEN 'WASHED / GIVEN'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE 'CHG (Chlorhexidine) bathing wipes%' THEN 'WASHED / GIVEN'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE 'Incontinence care%'then 'WASHED / GIVEN' 
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Incontinence care%'then 'WASHED / GIVEN' 
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%Bath not given – Other (comment)%' THEN 'NOT GIVEN'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%refused%' then 'Refused'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE LIKE '%CHG contraindicated%' then 'Contraindicated'
WHEN F.MEAS_VALUE = 'Bath not given – CHG contraindicated' then 'Contraindicated'
END AS BATH_STATUS
FROM 
PTS P
LEFT OUTER JOIN
FMEAS F
ON
P.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = F.FMEAS_PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
WHERE 
P.EFFECT_DATE = F.RECORDED_DATE 
ORDER BY
P.HOSPITAL,
P.DEPARTMENT_ID,
P.EFFECT_DATE,
P.Y_MRN,
F.RECORDED_DATE)
,
FIN
AS
(
SELECT DISTINCT
P.HOSPITAL,
P.DEPARTMENT_ID,
P.department_name,
P.EFFECT_DATE,
P.effective_time,
C.IP_LDA_ID,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.IP_LDA_ID 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.IP_LDA_ID 
ELSE NULL END AS IP_LDA_ID_A,
C.DISP_NAME,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.DISP_NAME
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.DISP_NAME 
ELSE NULL END AS DISP_NAME_A,
C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN TO_DATE('01/01/1900','MM/DD/YYYY') 
ELSE NULL END AS PLACEMENT_INSTANT_A,
C.REMOVAL_INSTANT,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.REMOVAL_INSTANT 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.REMOVAL_INSTANT 
ELSE NULL END AS REMOVAL_INSTANT_A,
C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE
ELSE NULL END AS PLACEMENT_INSTANT_DATE_A,
C.REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE 
ELSE NULL END AS REMOVAL_INSTANT_DATE_A,
C.CL,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.CL 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.CL 
ELSE NULL END AS CL_A,
C.CL_PATIENT_TYPE,
CASE WHEN TRUNC(C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT) <= TRUNC(P.effective_time) AND 
TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time)THEN C.CL_PATIENT_TYPE 
WHEN C.PLACEMENT_INSTANT IS NULL AND TRUNC(C.REMOVAL_INSTANT)>=  TRUNC(P.effective_time) THEN C.CL_PATIENT_TYPE
ELSE NULL END AS CL_PATIENT_TYPE_A,
P.RM_PATIENT_TYPE,
P.PAT_ID,
P.Y_MRN,
P.hosp_admsn_time,
P.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID,
P.RECORDED_TIME,
P.RECORDED_DATE,
P.meas_value,
P.Standard_Bath,
P.CHG,
P.BATH_STATUS
FROM 
PT2 P
LEFT OUTER JOIN
CL C
ON
P.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID =C.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID 
WHERE 
(P.effective_time between (select start_date from dd) AND (select end_date from dd)+1)
)
SELECT DISTINCT
P.EFFECT_DATE,
P.Y_MRN,
**CASE WHEN P.DEPARTMENT_ID IN (2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,
5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235) THEN 'CHG' 
WHEN P.IP_LDA_ID_A IS NOT NULL AND P.DEPARTMENT_ID NOT IN (2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,
5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235)THEN MIN(P.CL_PATIENT_TYPE_A) OVER (PARTITION BY P.PAT_ID,P.EFFECT_DATE) 
WHEN P.IP_LDA_ID_A IS NULL AND P.DEPARTMENT_ID NOT IN (2133009,4313023,4313015,4313016,4314007,4314009,4314027,5119219,5119221,5115578,73,5115579,5119222,5123216,
5133207,5119223,5101202,5133026,5119220,5120202,5119218,5119235)THEN P.RM_PATIENT_TYPE END AS PATIENT_TYPE,**
FROM 
FIN P
```

Comment: Could you simplify your problem? As you describe your case, it should be concern to only 2-3 tables, with about 10 lines of code to get the expected `patient_type`. After that you could apply it to your long, complicated query. So If you get the point of my comment, you could provide table structure of those 2-3 tables, with sample data, and your expected output so that we could help you build the right query.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Pham i added a screen shot.  my query is complicated because the report is complicated. any help would be much appreciated.